# edit text with label inside in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

can anyone know how to make this?

i think this is a editText
but how can i put a label and text at the same time?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a drop down list with different values for gender or are you just displaying two text fields?

Comment: its a edittext, with a textview. thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this out :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Gender" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the 'hint' property: 
android:hint="@string/hint_email"

*Then, the text label is ignored when you input a value.*

For setting color of hint texts, see [stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824009/change-edittext-hint-color-when-using-textinputlayout/30824183)