# Change EditText hint color when using TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-textattributes

I am using the new `TextInputLayout` from the design library. I am able to get it to show and to change the color of the floating label. Unfortunately the actual `EditText` hint is now always white.

I have tried changing the hintColor in XML, styles, and programmatically and also tried using the `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`
but the `EditText` hint always shows white.

Here is my XML for my `TextInputLayout` and `EditText`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.support.design:hintTextAppearance="@style/GreenTextInputLayout">


    <EditText

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:hint="@string/city" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And here is the style I am using for the `TextInputLayout` (I tried making the `hintTextColor` attribute black but didn't do anything for me):

```
<style name="GreenTextInputLayout" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/homestory_green</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the parent view had a style for a 3rd party library that was causing the EditText to be white.

```
android:theme="@style/com_mixpanel_android_SurveyActivityTheme"
```

Once I removed this everything worked fine.

Answer (score 194):

Define `android:textColorHint` in your application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176559#c1)

---

**Or,** in your layout, like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.support.design:hintTextAppearance="@style/GreenTextInputLayout"
    android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text">
```

Comment: It works for me but the hint's color is not set at fragment & view creation, I have to click on my `EditText` for the hint color to be set on all inputs within the view... haven't found any fix to that yet (`requestFocus()` and `performClick()` don't do the trick unfortunately).

Comment: worked when used as attribute :     <EditText
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:gravity="top|right"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:hint="hint text" 
   android:textColorHint="#919389"
                        />

Comment: The problem is that if colorControlActivated is set, it will override textColorHint.

Answer (score 82):

Create **custom** style in style.xml

```
<style name="EditTextHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout xml file, add **theme** attribute as below

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

hope this works

Comment: Showing "Error inflating class EditText". Please help !

Comment: @Coder some of the attributes he added are for 21+

Answer (score 62):

Add textColorHint property to your edit text

```
android:textColorHint="#F6F6F6"
```

or whichever color you want

Answer (score 42):

got the same problem. Resolved by putting these lines in **parent** theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/AccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

If you put these

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
```

in a separate style and apply it to *TextInputLayout* or *Edittext* it won't appear. You **HAVE** to place it in application's parent theme.

Answer (score 42):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can customize the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) the hint text color using:

- In the layout:

  - **`app:hintTextColor`** attribute : the color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active
  - **`android:textColorHint`** attribute: the color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled)

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     app:hintTextColor="@color/mycolor"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_hint_selector"
     .../>
```

[image][image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Simple way to manage the state of hint text! Brilliant answer! However I can not declare `app:hintTextColor` in the style but in layout only.

Comment: Just figured, can also declare `<item name="hintTextColor">@color/lsHintTextColor</item>` in the style.

Comment: It's really odd that most responses didn't clarify this. I struggled with this all day just for that reason. Thanks for saving me.

Comment: how would i modify app:hintTextColor programmatically ? Layout.hintTextColor does not modify the app:hintTextcolor

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure what causes your problem put this code works perfectly for me. I think it has something to do with using the correct xml namespace (`xmlns`). I'm not sure if using android.support.design without xml namespace attribute is supported. Or it has something to do with the `textColorHint` attribute you are using on the EditText itself.

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/GreenTextInputLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test"
        android:inputType="text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="GreenTextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This still works like what I have. The problem I am having is that before the user touches the EditText, the EditText color is white. When the user touches the EditText, the TextInputLayout label is green and works fine.

Comment: This works for the floating hint, but not the hint inside the empty EditText control. For that, update the application theme as per [@mbelsky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31086001/383414)

Comment: By the way, the default app:hintTextAppearance style is `@style/TextAppearance.Design.Hint`, so you might want to use that as your `parent` rather than `@android:style/TextAppearance` or `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat`

Answer (score 19):

Refer the below code it worked for me.But it will affect all your controls color.

```
 <!-- In your style.xml file -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <!--EditText hint color-->
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/default_app_white</item>
           <!-- TextInputLayout text color-->
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText on-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText  in un-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/default_app_white</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 16):

In the TextInputLayout that holds the EditText, add:

```
android:textColorHint="someColor"
```

Answer (score 14):

A lot answers but need only a line for this:

**android:textColorHint="#000000"**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

if you are using the Material design library. Currently, I am using the version

> **implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'**

**1 - Set color when TextInputLayout is resting.**

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/your_color_hint</item>
```

**2 - Set color when TextInputLayout is floating/focused/tapped.**

```
<item name="hintTextColor">@color/your_color_floating_hint</item>
```

**3 - Set color of the line under TextInputLayout.**

```
<item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/TextViewColor_line</item>
```

**4 - Set color of the error under TextInputLayout.**

```
<item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `android:textColorHint="@color/color_black"` inside `TextInputlayout` It worked for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:textColorHint="@color/color_black"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_state"
                    style="@style/profile_editTextStyle"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/billingState"
                    android:text="@string/billingState"
                     />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

According to this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176559

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:textColorHint="#A7B7C2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_confirm_password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Confirm password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

It works in 23.1.1

Answer (score 6):

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Use textColorHint to set the color that you want as the Hint color for the EditText. The thing is that Hint in the EditText disappears not when you type something, but immediately when the EditText gets focus (with a cool animation). You will notice this clearly when you switch focus away and to the EditText.

Answer (score 5):

**try this may this help**

```
      edittext.addTextChangedListener(new  TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onTextChanged", 2000).show();;
            //newuser.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "afterTextChanged", 2000).show();;

        }
    });
```

Comment: why did you put it in onTextChanged listener?

Answer (score 5):

late but it may help someone i have done like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:textColorHint="#8cffffff">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/security_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:backgroundTint="#8cffffff" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
```

change your colorAccent to your desired color inside your Theme,this will change your EditText line,Cursor as well as your hint

or you can also include this style inside your style.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

then inside your TextInputLayout you can put it like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/password"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textWebPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> The hint should be set on the TextInputLayout, rather than the EditText. If a hint is specified on the child EditText in XML, the TextInputLayout might still work correctly; TextInputLayout will use the EditText's hint as its floating label. However, future calls to modify the hint will not update TextInputLayout's hint. To avoid unintended behavior, call setHint(CharSequence) and getHint() on TextInputLayout, instead of on EditText.

Try setting `android:hint` and `app:hintTextColor` on `TextInputLayout` instead of on `TextInputEditText`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete customization of the google material text input layout. This maybe helpful for you

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:textColorHint="@color/tint"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_user"
        app:startIconTint="@color/tint"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_45sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_45sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_45sdp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_45sdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/red"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
        <!-- for password 
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/tint" -->
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp" 
            android:padding="0dp" 
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Not Helpful please change yor answer

Answer (score 3):

This Should 100% work

```
android:textColorHint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_passdword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etaddrfess_ciwty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/frutiger"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/address_city"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>``
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using new androidx Material design library `com.google.android.material`
then you can use colorstatelist to control hint text color in focused, hovered and default state as follows. (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773896/5700434))

In `res/color/text_input_box_stroke.xml` put something like the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fcc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="#cfc" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="#ccf"/>
</selector>
```

Then in your `styles.xml` you would put:

```
<style name="MtTILStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
</style>
```

Finally indicate your style in the actual `TextInputLayout`
For some reason you also need to set `android:textColorHint` for default text color of hint:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout_id"
    style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:textColorHint="#ccf"
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set hint color on TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to set theme attribute to TextInputLayout, the theme was also getting applied to its child view edittext, which I didn't wanted.

So the solution which worked for me was to add a custom style to the "app:hintTextAppearance" property of the TextInputLayout.

In styles.xml add the following style:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_12</item>
</style>
```

And apply this style to the "app:hintTextAppearance" property of the TextInputLayout as below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobile_num_til"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_56"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title_tv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/title_tv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sub_title_tv"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_30"
        android:padding="@dimen/dim_8"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutTextAppearance"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_round_corner_grey_outline">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile_num_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

The high light color is White:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextStyle"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:drawableLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:hint="Mobile" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style:  TextStyle

```
    <style name="TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
     </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience with this similar issue & the required solution.

**Requirement:**

- Need to create customize `TextInputEditText` (can say some should be transparent and some should be not but use custom colors for various events)

**Problem faced:**

- `android:textColorHint` is not working as required.

**Solutions tried, which failed:**

- Used `android:textColorHint` in style and applied to `TextInputEditText`. No results or difference.
- Set `android:textColorHint` in application's theme applied. It do helped but it was now set for entire application. (Not up-to mark to requirement)

*After a lot of RnD, the best SOLUTION found was in an article which described that we need to apply **theme** to `TextInputLayout` or to it's parent view rather then only applying **style** to `TextInputEditText` or to it's parent view.*

Please check [TextInputLayout proper Theming](https://medium.com/fw-engineering/textinputlayout-proper-theming-dde422e86c43) which told that how we are at wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to change the label color when it is lifted to top. But setting `textColorHint` changes the color at every state. So, this worked for me:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       ...
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       ...
    </style>
```

This will change the color when the input is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextInputLayout.setDefaultHintTextColor`