# How to set * in hint in textinputLayout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM2mM.png)I want to set hint * in edittext in red color as a required field. Please give me suggestion

I want this star only in red color other as it is

Comment: How do you have your hint displayed? Is it a text view above the edit text field or you used text input layout?

Comment: Have you even googled before asking a question?

Comment: Use ForegroundSpan to only make the star red.You can find example implemenation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3514435/4321808

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change EditText hint color when using TextInputLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824009/change-edittext-hint-color-when-using-textinputlayout)

Comment: post your design here first

Comment: Please dont answer if you cant read question properly. @azizbekin

Comment: any solution on this??

Answer (score 6):

Store a string in strings file like this (if you want to make email required):

```
<string name="email">Email<font fgcolor="red">*</font></string>
```

and in your editText set hint like this:

```
android:hint="@string/email"
```

Answer (score 6):

**1.** Add below `string` in your `strings.xml` for `hints`.

```
<string name="hints"><![CDATA[Member ID(Don\'t include dash or space)<font color=\'#cc0029\'>*</font>]]></string>
```

**2.** Programmatically set this `string` as `hint` text from your `Activity` class.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_member_id);
editText.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.hints)));
```

**3.** Here is your `EditText` in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_member_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer helps you please mark this as accepted answer by clicking on tick mark. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below one

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Add text here (demo text)*"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
           />
```

Comment: you have change the images ok earlier you were having red text image

Answer (score 0):

Add this hint in xml code like this  `android:hint="Put your hint text"`

Comment: do you know question or not?