# TextInputLayout - Change floating label hint color if EditText is not empty and not focused

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Res state - hint color black, good
[image]

Focused state, empty - hint color gray, good
[image]

Focused state, not empty - hint color gray, good
[image]

Res state, not empty - hint color black, not good, should be gray
[image]

**How to change hint color if editText is not empty and not focused?**

This is my current code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    style="@style/AuthInput"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:theme="@style/AuthInput"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
        style="@style/AuthEditText"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and styles:

```
<style name="AuthInput">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/inputHintActive</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824009/change-edittext-hint-color-when-using-textinputlayout

Comment: @quicklearner sorry, but I didn't find there correct answer for me.

Comment: Hello @RexHunt! I'm facing the same problem as you. I'd like to know if you have found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Hello @Marlon! Unfortunately no.

Comment: Hello @RexHunt, Please share if you have found a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Omer it was so long ago, we just set hint color to always be gray, as we didn't find a way for that.

Comment: hey, did u find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/transparant</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/transparant</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item> // set grey color for hint
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hint color always black

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you, what are you asking for ?

Comment: I need hint color black only when editText is empty and not focused, otherwise gray color.

Comment: "android:textColorHint" stands for hint's disabled color, which was what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hint color by

```
editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

and if you want to clear the focus of your edit text then use

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is for editText hint, but I need for floating hint and if it's possible, not programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Change your `TextInputLayout` style

Your `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hintText"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Your `TextInputLayout` style chnage color according to your test

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorBlack</item>

    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

Comment: sorry, but it's not help me

Comment: i have tested and then posted this answer still whats problem you have faced  ?

Comment: in your example, hint color always same, but I need hint color black only when editText is empty and not focused, otherwise gray color.

Comment: change color in this line   <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorBlack</item>

Comment: and also change in this line  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorGray</item>

Comment: I've tried it, this way color will be black on res state.

Comment: Please take a look at the images, I've shown all states there.

Comment: you can you both property i have double check  but some how it not work for you

Comment: I'll try your solution in the fresh project and let you know.

Comment: I've checked and when we leave input with text, hint color stays black, but I need so it should be gray. Please take a look at the images again and notes for them. For the last image I've said "Res state, not empty - hint color black, not good, **should be gray**". If we change hint color in the styles, it will be changed for other states.