# TextInputLayout hint color in error state

Tags: android, android-design-library

As per Googles Material Guidelines:

https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout

TextInputLayout hint should be the same color as the Error message:

[image]

However it is not like that and when I call `setError("My error")` only the underline and the error message show up in red.

How can I change this behavior to account for Google's own guidelines?

Comment: Can you show the actual look that you are experiencing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709066/how-to-set-textinputlayout-error-message-colour

Comment: Try out with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824009/change-edittext-hint-color-when-using-textinputlayout

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 18):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/tilSample"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSample"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:hint="android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="colorRed">#f44336</color>
</resources>
```

**EDIT**

We can manipulate the error and hint colours in code also using:

```
tilSample.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.error_appearance);  
tilSample.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.error_appearance);
```

Comment: for that, you can use java code and change the error and hint accordingly on validation. 
I have added java part also, not tested but it should work as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Now this is default behaviour. To achieve this, just update your support library version to 28+.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can manipulate the error as helper text because if you set an error it will definitely change the hint color, so I just used `helperText` instead of `setError`, here is an example

**XML File**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                  android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUserName"
                  android:layout_width="@dimen/view_0x"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  style="@style/errorEnabledtextInputLayoutStyle">
    
                     <EditText
                           android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                           android:gravity="center_vertical"
                           android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                           android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGray"
                           android:hint="@string/aap_ka_naam"
                           android:singleLine="true"
                           style="@style/standardTextViewStyle"
                           tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
    
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**edit_text_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:top="-3dp" android:left="-3dp" android:right="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
               <padding android:bottom="50dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"android:left="5dp"/>
               <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
     </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Styles**

```
<style name="errorEnabledtextInputLayoutStyle">
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorGraySix</item>
        <item name="helperTextTextColor">@color/colorNegative</item>
        <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

**Function**

```
fun TextInputLayout.setErrorText(error : String, editText: EditText) {
     this.helperText = error
     editText.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources,
            R.color.colorNegative, null)
      )
}
```

**Usage**

```
textInputLayoutUserName.setErrorText(getString(R.string.name_error), editTextUserName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email_layout"
                android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    style="@style/TextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:gravity="center|left|bottom"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_effective"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Style File:

```
   <style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
    </style>
```

Snapshot:

[image: In image : TextInputLayout hint should be the same color as the Error message]

Comment: this, and all the rest of the answers, changes hint color, not hint color on the error state

Comment: @MichelReap Can you please elaborate what do you exactly want? There is some confusion.

Comment: I want the behavior google states ont he guidelines: Hint remains the accent color until the validation, where the hint turns the same color as the underline and the error message. If not on error state, then the color is the accent.

Comment: @MichelReap Means what you want that initially Hint color is accent when any error occurs then line , error and hint all the colors are same i.e gray. and in all other cases, hint remains accent.

Answer (score 0):

1. TextInputLayout in Xml

   ```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/tx_login_password"
           app:errorEnabled="true"
           style="@style/text_input_style"
           app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
           app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_Apearence"
           android:layout_below="@id/tx_login_username"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           app:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
           android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
           app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_Apearence"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="Password"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:typeface="sans"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:lines="1"
               android:elegantTextHeight="true"
               android:textAlignment="viewStart"
               android:layout_gravity="start"
               android:id="@+id/password"
               android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
               app:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
               style="@style/EditText_style"
               />
       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   ```
2. text_Apearence in style.xml file from resourses

```html
<style name="text_Apearence" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/react_blue</item>
    </style>
   

 1.  3. Style for Text Input Layout text_input_style XML file

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

1. Style for Text Input Layout text_input_style XML file

```html
<style name="text_Apearence" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/react_blue</item>
    </style>
```

[Image Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yaOC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "helperTextTextColor" attribute to do this.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            app:hintTextColor="@color/color_login_text_hint"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/error_color">
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method which you may would try

```
fun wrapInCustomStyle(myText: String): Spannable? {
val spannable = SpannableString(myText) Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

//Test 'Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSIT' Too if not working

spannable.setSpan(

    AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL), 0,
    myText.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
) 
return spannable
```

}

```
InputLayout.error=wrapInCustomStyle("sample")
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<style name="text_Apearence" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/react_blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/react_blue</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: colorActivatedHighlight and colorControlActivated are theme attributes. Those need to be set in the theme.