# Change the TextInputLayout outline color

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to customize a TextInputLayout with material style. I managed to set the focused state to the colors I want:

[image]

Using

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
     android:theme="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
     android:textColorHint="#fff"
     app:boxStrokeColor="#fff"
     .....>
          <EditText ...
```

where the style is:

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
</style>
```

But when the textinput is not focused I get this look:

[image]

How can I change the color of the black line to be white too?

Comment: Can we add outlinedbox on multiautocomplete text view?

Comment: using the accepted answer only on focused color changed not when control is not focused.. did it worked for you ? how?

Comment: Thanks for working sample! Applied this and some adjustments and got material theme working.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Use this style to apply border color and border width like this :

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
</style>
```

get Additional details about styling from this [link](https://material.io/components/text-fields/)

Add below line in your `colors.xml` file that overrides default color for `TextInputLayout`

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>
```

Comment: This changes the outline in focused mode but still have a black outline when the edit text is not focused =(

Comment: @Addev check my edited answer and add color in your colors.xml file.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt thank you. But android studio says that resource is private and could disappear without notice. There are no better solution?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt What about hint text color in non-focused mode??

Comment: @kreker add tools:override="true" in the color tag, to resolve this issue

Comment: @RutvikBhatt if I changed the default color in color then it will change the outlined box color in all activities but i want different colour of stroke for different activities, Then what to do with it?

Comment: As of material library 1.1.0 this answer is no longer the best way.

Comment: Is there a way to add a gradient color?

Comment: @kroot what is the best way? I'm using 1.1.0-alpha07

Comment: How can I achieve the same `mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color` color override programmatically?

Comment: Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense: not working in "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"

Answer (score 107):

As of version [1.1.0-alpha02](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) of the Material Components for Android it works to simply create a [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource) for these items. The procedure is as follows:

Create a new resource directory "color" in res and inside color add a color resource file named "text_input_box_stroke.xml" `res/color/text_input_box_stroke.xml` put something like the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fcc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="#cfc" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="#ccf"/>
</selector>
```

Then in your `styles.xml` you would put:

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
</style>
```

Finally indicate your style for the actual `TextInputLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout_id"
    style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
    ...
```

Comment: This actually worked for me using `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`. 
But I used `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` as a base style (not Dense)

Comment: @VadimKotov it did not work for me, using the same configurations

Comment: how to change border with of the InputBox since it's thicker in focus state

Comment: Perfectly working, I added some other items to the style, to change also the hint color, etc

Comment: This has to be what was the intended method rather than all the advice to override an internal color that may stop existing

Comment: If you put `text_input_box_stroke.xml` in the `color` folder, you can skip creating a style and just set `app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_box_stroke"` directly on the `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 14):

As of Material Components Alpha 7 you simply create a color selector file as so:
colors/text_input_outline_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/buttonDark"/>
    <item android:state_hovered="true" android:color="@color/buttonDark"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/buttonDark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/buttonDark"/>
</selector>
```

For more context into how this is being set. Here is relevant source code:

```
ColorStateList boxStrokeColorStateList =
    MaterialResources.getColorStateList(context, a, R.styleable.TextInputLayout_boxStrokeColor);
if (boxStrokeColorStateList != null && boxStrokeColorStateList.isStateful()) {
  defaultStrokeColor = boxStrokeColorStateList.getDefaultColor();
  disabledColor =
      boxStrokeColorStateList.getColorForState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, -1);
  hoveredStrokeColor =
      boxStrokeColorStateList.getColorForState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_hovered}, -1);
  focusedStrokeColor =
      boxStrokeColorStateList.getColorForState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, -1);
} else {
  // If attribute boxStrokeColor is not a color state list but only a single value, its value
  // will be applied to the box's focus state.
  focusedStrokeColor =
      a.getColor(R.styleable.TextInputLayout_boxStrokeColor, Color.TRANSPARENT);
  defaultStrokeColor =
      ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color);
  disabledColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.mtrl_textinput_disabled_color);
  hoveredStrokeColor =
      ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.mtrl_textinput_hovered_box_stroke_color);
}
```

From this list you can see that you want to ensure you are using a color selector with all states defined, or it will default back to another color.

Comment: There are issues with this solution. This selector will not change default color. Tested. Had to override mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/593

Answer (score 5):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

<item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#FFFFFF"/></selector>
```

**create the color directory and inside that create a resource file 
paste the above code in color directory xml file 
 and in text input layout style paste the below line**

```
<item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/focus_tint_list</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

Matrial Edit Text

Step 1: Add library in build.gradle(Module App) module dependency section

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'

Step 2 : xml Code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:boxStrokeColor="#0000FF"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/lable" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

First Remove from your TextInputLayout

```
<item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/YourColor</item>
```

Second, add a new color attribute

```
 <color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true" >YourColor</color>
```

Must write the same name mtrl_**textinput_default_box_stroke_color** do n't change

Answer (score 4):

I'm creating dynamically my screen. I'm using `TextInputLayout` and create my dynamic edit text in `TextInputLayout`. If you want to give `TextInputLayout` to the border, do the following steps in order.

1- include Build.gradle;

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

2- in Kotlin code;

```
val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(this)
        textInputLayout.apply {
            boxStrokeColor = Color.parseColor("#E68A06")
            setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE)
            setHintTextAppearance(R.style.ValidatableInputLayoutStyle_OutlineBox_HintInputLayoutStyle)
            setBoxCornerRadii(16f, 16f, 16f, 16f)
            setPadding(4, 0, 0, 0)
        }
```

3- style.xml

```
<style name="ValidatableInputLayoutStyle.OutlineBox.HintInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
```

[My Component image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPTI.png)

Answer (score 3):

I created a default config.

```
 <style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance</item>
    <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter</item>
    <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <!-- Floating label appearance here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <!-- Error message appearance here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a Theme and override "colorOnSurface" attr.

```
<style name="AppTheme.LoginScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

2. Apply the theme to your login activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".login.ui.login.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LoginScreenTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**. Use `1.2.0-alpha05` or later

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

**Step 2 - Important!**. Make sure your app theme is or is a descendant of `Theme.MaterialComponents`. See [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Once that's set all attribute setting work as expected.

**Step 3.** Use the attribute setting from the [specification](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/filledTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label_text"
    app:helperTextEnabled="true"
    app:helperText="@string/helper_text"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="20"
    app:startIconContentDescription="@string/leading_icon_content_desc"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_favorite_24">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Step 2 is really very important, Thank you..!

Answer (score 2):

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:boxStrokeColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ***app:boxStrokeColor="#fff"***
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. add this line to your colors.xml file

```
<color  name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#4169E1</color>
```

Step 2. add this property in TextInputLayout

```
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

##### Steps to follow

###### 1. Create `ColorStateList` for `boxStrokeColor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" />
</selector>
```

###### 2. Create `ColorStateList` for `android:textColorHint`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" />
</selector>
```

###### 3. Set view attributes - There are 3 ways that you can do this.

###### I. Using attribute set

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_hint"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/box_stroke_color"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorSurface">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

###### II. Using explicit style

###### Define custom style

```
<style name="CustomTextInputStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/box_stroke_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_hint</item>
</style>
```

###### Set style

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/CustomTextInputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

###### III. Using default style attribute - set global style for `TextInputLayout`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    ...
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    ...

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/CustomTextInputStyle</item>
</style>
```

### Explanation

There are various ways to change `TextInputLayout` box stroke color and hint text color.

The responsible attribute for box outline color is `boxStrokeColor`.
First let's create `ColorStateList` in xml format. Create Android `color` resource directory and create new resource file named `box_stroke_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" />
</selector>
```

I referred resources of material design library. See how this is done in material design library https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/color/mtrl_outlined_stroke_color.xml

To change hint text color, we have to set two attributes,

1. `hintTextColor` (The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active)
2. `android:textColorHint` (The color of the label in all other text field states, such as resting and disabled)

How do I know which attributes are required to change? I checked attributes defined in theme `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`. Look at parent theme if not defined in the child theme. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/788866e4483621e2222f649e617ee95f7aa9caa6/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/styles.xml#L88 (This may vary in master branch)

```
app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorSurface"
```

Note that `hintTextColor` is not stateful.
But `android:textColorHint` is stateful.

Let's create custom `ColorStateList` for `android:textColorHint`.
Referred this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/color/mtrl_indicator_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorSurface" />
</selector>
```

Note that I have used `?attr/colorSurface`, because generally it's value is white in light theme and black in dark theme. You could use `@android:color/white` directly if you don't want dynamic color adjustments.

There are several ways that you can set box stroke color attribute value,
Attribute values are resolved using `context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes()`.
If value is defined in multiple places, the following order determines which attribute value is ultimately applied.

1. AttributeSet - Value defined in layout xml file.
2. Style - Value defined in explicit style. (Retrieve it through `theme.getExplicitStyle(AttributeSet)`)
3. defStyleAttr - Default style attribute, which is the third argument of view class constructor.
4. defStyleRes - Default style resource, which is the fourth argument of view class constructor.
5. Theme - If not defined in all of the above, theme attribute value is resolved.

Let's see them one by one

1. Using AttributeSet

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_hint"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/box_stroke_color"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorSurface">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

2. Using explicit style

Define custom style in styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="CustomTextInputStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/box_stroke_color</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_hint</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

Define explicit style for the widget

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/CustomTextInputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

3. Using default style attribute - This is used to define global style for a view. How do you know which attribute is required to set? Just check default value of third argument of any view constructor. For material `TextInputLayout` this value is `com.google.android.material.R.attr.textInputStyle`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    ...
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    ...

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/CustomTextInputStyle</item>
</style>
```

4. Using default style resource - This is only applicable when creating widgets programmatically. If you check fourth argument of the constructor of any view except material design views, you can see `defStyleRes` parameter. If `theme.obtainStyledAttributes()` cannot resolve from the above ways, then it looks for attribute in default style resource. This is not applicable in material design library widgets, because this value is hard coded in those widgets and not exposed to change programmatically. (It is internally applied through `theme.applyStyle()`)
5. Using app theme - This is not possible in material design widgets, because `defStyleRes` is hard coded in material design widgets and it takes precedence over app theme attributes.

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/box_stroke_color</item>
<item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_hint</item>
```

Above is only applicable in Android Sdk provided widgets.

Answer (score 2):

**Despite being late, I hope this solution still helps you.**

> **Create a Color Resource file (I've named it **"*col_str*"**) in the res>color folder. Don't forget to create a folder named "Color" in the
> res folder if one does not exist.**

**col_str :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

**In your XML file :**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your Hint"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/col_str">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This works even for text color.

Answer (score 0):

---> First customize style

```
 <style name="Widget.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Second If you want to this style for all TextinputLayout in whole app.

so add this style to your parent theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.TextInputLayout.FilledBox</item>
</style>
```

If you just want to add only for this particular input field

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
 
 .....>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="VerifyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the border color:

```
 app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gray" //for border color
```

For the hint color:

```
 app:hintTextColor="@color/puce" //for hint color
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:theme="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
                android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textxhdpi"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In the Styles:

```
<resources
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.neurosales.Body2</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.neurosales.Body2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#fff</item>
    <item name="app:hintTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

In Color:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to set the color for the outline box in unfocused mode instead of the default one, you have to add this line in colors.xml file which will override the default color for the outline box.

`<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>`

for more details:
[Click here](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/android-issue-change-border-color-or-box-stroke-for-unfocused-textinputlayout-in-android/)