# how to change the color of outline or border of textInputLayout not focused?

Tags: android, colors, styles, android-textinputlayout

I am tring to change the color of outline or border of the textInputLayout, I dont know why its not changeing, I search and find some solutions but didnt work for me.

here I put the style and then apply it in the textInputLayout

```
<style name="WhiteOutlineBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/snow </item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextLabel</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="passwordToggleTint">@color/snow</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/snow</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/snow</item>

</style>

<!--  this style for the hint text lable in textInputLayout -->
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/snow</item>
</style>
```

here the code of appling it in textInputLayout in xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ed_oldPass"
            style="@style/WhiteOutlineBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/WhiteOutlineBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@color/snow"
                android:textColor="@color/snow"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/old_pass_ed_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

the stroke color, hintTextAppearence, hint color and pass toggle tint color *changed* but others no ,what I want is changing the color of border when its not focused how to do that? please help and thanks in advance

Comment: The best answer I've found so far is this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50818399/1177959

Comment: @Sotti thank you , thats help but if I want to change it in some pages , how to do that?

Comment: Given that all is very hacky, I wouldn't know how to do it. I'm very surprised about the lack of basic customization on the TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **`boxStrokeColor`** attribute.It can work with a selector.

Use something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
        ..>
```

or

```
<style name="WhiteOutlineBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...."/>  <!-- unfocused -->
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem if one wants to change just one TextInputLayout programmatically, the problem is the property [defaultStrokeColor](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/83e36b62e2def1d80b05a7ffe81ea383f607bef0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L369) is not accessible, the only way to change it is through overriding the colour [mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/83e36b62e2def1d80b05a7ffe81ea383f607bef0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L537) or uses a [state list colour](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/83e36b62e2def1d80b05a7ffe81ea383f607bef0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L524) but in both cases, you need the styles on XML.

In another hand, the property [focusedStrokeColor](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/83e36b62e2def1d80b05a7ffe81ea383f607bef0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L371) is accessible through [setBoxStrokeColor](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/83e36b62e2def1d80b05a7ffe81ea383f607bef0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L842), so it is possible to change it programmatically without any special code.

A solution for it, if reflection is an option for you, of course, is to change the accessibility of the property in run-time, the following code does the job on material-1.1.0:

```kotlin
fun TextInputLayout.setDefaultStrokeColor(
    color: Int
) {
    try {
        val defaultStrokeColor = TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("defaultStrokeColor")
        defaultStrokeColor.isAccessible = true
        defaultStrokeColor.set(this, color)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        // failed to change the color
    }
}
```

uses it as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

```kotlin
yourView.setDefaultStrokeColor(yourColor)
```

Comment: what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

add this to your color.xml

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#BDC3C7</color>
```

it overrides default unfocused outline color

Comment: but all textinputlayout changes. Not for specific acitivity theme