# Change the TextInputLayout outline box color programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I would like to change outline of the TextInputLayout programmatically, but I cannot seem to get it to work. There is an option to do it via XML ([question by other SO user using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817383/change-the-textinputlayout-outline-color/54929215#54929215)), but that is unusable for me as I need to have dynamic coloring. I currently have the  following layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:id="@+id/color_outline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Choose color"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I've attempted to apply coloring by looking at the various box methods of the TextInputLayout, but it did not have any effect.

```
internal fun String.toIntColor() = Integer.parseInt(this.replaceFirst("#", ""), 16)


val colorOutline: TextInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.color_outline)
colorOutline.boxStrokeColor = "#006699".toIntColor()
```

How can I color it dynamically, like in the picture below?

Current situation:
[image]

Desired situation: (photoshopped)
[image]

[Similar question, but focussing on XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817383/change-the-textinputlayout-outline-color/54929215#54929215)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can the method **`setBoxStrokeColorStateList`**.

Something like:

```
//Color from rgb
int color = Color.rgb(255,0,0);
//Color from hex string
int color2 = Color.parseColor("#FF11AA");

int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_hovered}, // hovered
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] { }  // 
    };

    int[] colors = new int[] {
        color,
        color,
        color,
        color2
    };

    ColorStateList myColorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColorStateList(myColorList);
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed seems to be added recently, thank you for the swift notice. Will mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

**In Kotlin**
I have modified the @Gabriele's answer to make it working for me

You can define an extension function as :

```
private fun TextInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColorSelector() {
    //Color from rgb
    int color = Color.rgb(255,0,0);
    //Color from hex string
    val defaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.indicator_def)

    val states = arrayOf {
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused),  // focused
    //    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_hovered), // hovered
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled), // enabled
        intArrayOf() // default
    }

    val colors = intArrayOf(color, // focused color
    /*color,*/ // hovered color
    color, // enabled color
    defaultColor) // default color

    val myColorList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
    setBoxStrokeColorStateList(myColorList)
}
```

and just call it for any TextInputLayout in your app like

```
TextInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColorSelector(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
```

Comment: This is not valid Kotlin syntax.