# How to change the border color of edittext inside the TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using TextInputLayout around edittext. I want to change the border color of the edit text which is present inside the TextInputLayout.

xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/Test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Csharp

```
    private TextInputEditText editor;
    editor = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.Test6);
    editor.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Red, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
```

This above code works correctly, if the edit text is not present inside the TextInputLayout. Only gets problem while using the edittext inside the TextInputLayout. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use the boxStrokeColor attribute

Answer (score 1):

create drawable file in drawable folder i.e.
drawable_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- Background Color -->
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

  <!-- Border Color -->
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e7e7e7e7" />

  <!-- Round Corners -->
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

and set this drawable to edittext

```
 drawble = "@drawable/drawble_name"
```

change color of border as per your requirement

Comment: Sorry, I think you have understood wrongly. I need to change the default existing border color of the edit text.

Comment: You can use tint in the xml then to change the default border of the edittext

Comment: Instead of shape?

Comment: yes, i.e. tint = "@color/specific_color" in edittext tag

Comment: I had tried this, if I focus the edit text it gets to blue color and in unfocus tint color works.

Answer (score 1):

put the style in your style,

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
</style>
```

and add the following color to your color.xml

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>
```

[Change the TextInputLayout outline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817383/change-the-textinputlayout-outline-color)